# EJB entity manager remove() result in Cannot delete or update a parent row

Tags: jquery

I use jquery `.find('input')[0]` which gives me a element like this

```
<input name='world' value='hello'>
```

I want to change the value of this textfield. I then `find('input')[0].val('')`, but it gave me a type error. Any insight please ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `:first` to get the first input.

```
find('input:first').val('your value here')
```

or

```
find('input:eq(0)').val('your value here');
```

When you do `find('input')[0]`, you're actually getting the DOM element and since it's no longer wrapped in a jquery object the `.val` property will not work.

If you really want to use your previous code then you could use the native DOM property `value`

```
find('input')[0].value
```

Comment: thanks. I just tried. find(‘input:eq(0)’) returns the same thing as

Comment: find('input'). sorry I lost connection.

Comment: first `$('input:eq(0)')` second `$('input:eq(1)')`  etc

Comment: $('#undo').parent().parent().children(0).find('input:eq(0)') and ('#undo').parent().parent().children(0).find('input') gave the same output.

Comment: I would need to see your HTML structure. What that means is that there's only one output in that node.

Comment: <table align="left">
<tr>
<span><form id="form6b"/>
<td><a>jklfjaljflsaj</a></td>
<td><input value="Default" name="variation" disabled="disabled"/></td>
<td><input value="faslkfjlsajl" name="value"/></td>
<td><input value="sajlfjsl" name="note"/></td>
</form>
</span>
<td><font color="red"/><span>12</span></td>
</tr>
</table>

Comment: I don't see `undo`, post your complete code and paste it to the original post.

Comment: undo is a link, on which I click the text in side note and variation got cleared. The code is beyond the capacity of the post. sorry for that

Comment: Ok, here's the suggestion i have for you. You can solve this on your own. All you need to do is `console.log( $('#undo').parent().parent() )` Then do that each step of the way and see what your output is, your selector is not right. I can't help you further because i don't know your html structure. Maybe don't use .children(0) it seems you may be selecting just one node and you really want all. You will have to experiment and see.